# MongoDB what's the best practice for setting write concern for consistent reads

Tags: mongodb

I'm not an expert of mongo, just using our company's mongo cluster as my database. There're three hosts in the cluster.  I usually encounter a data inconsistent problem: query right after I insert but got nothing.

So I set write concern with option `'w' : 3` to all my insert operation. That gives my expected results.

Yesterday one of host is down, leaving two alive hosts in the cluster. All read-only operation is good, but since my insert operation required `'w': 3` write concern, so they're blocking forever.

I think setting `w` option to the number of all machines is not a good idea, I should not expect all host in the cluster to be alive, or even more, I believe my code should not have those details about the cluster, the node failure is handled inside the cluster. But data consistency is super important to me, how should I config the write concern options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use write concern 'majority' to ensure your writes are replicated to the majority of the members.

Couple with read concern 'majority' gives you read-your-own-writes consistency.

See [Causal Consistency and Read and Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/#causal-consistency-and-read-and-write-concerns)